# natbib bibliography reference starts not from 1

Tags: natbib

please help me to order references in text from 1 and increase the number through the whole text (like a normal). Now it starts with 6 and the second reference has order 2. Can't find why...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\begin{document}

\title{\textbf{XXX}\\ XXXXXXXX}
\author{XXX\\[1cm]{ XXX}}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\section{XXX}
XXX.\citep{noauthor_cern_nodate}. XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.\citep{bell_beyond_2009}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{bibliography/sample}

\end{document}
```

And my bib file:

```
@article{bell_beyond_2009,
    title = {Beyond the Data Deluge},
    volume = {323},
    rights = {© 2009 American Association for the Advancement of Science},
    issn = {0036-8075, 1095-9203},
    url = {http://science.sciencemag.org/content/323/5919/1297},
    doi = {10.1126/science.1170411},
    abstract = {The demands of data-intensive science represent a challenge for diverse scientific communities.
    The demands of data-intensive science represent a challenge for diverse scientific communities.},
    pages = {1297--1298},
    number = {5919},
    journal = {Science},
    author = {Bell, Gordon and Hey, Tony and Szalay, Alex},
    year = {2009},
    langid = {english},
    pmid = {19265007}
}
@article{noauthor_cern_nodate,
    title = {{CERN} Data Centre passes the 200-petabyte milestone {\textbar} {CERN}},
    url = {https://home.cern/news/news/computing/cern-data-centre-passes-200-petabyte-milestone},
    year = {2018-12-11},
    author = {Mélissa Gaillard}
}
```

Comment: your file produce [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFa4K.png) is that not what you expect? numbers 1 and 2 , no 6.

Comment: Yep, I've just recompile it, and the output is the same as on your pic. But why doest it start from 2 not from 1?

Comment: Off-topic: It's wrong to use the `@article` entry type for piece authored by Gaillard. The `@article` entry type should be used only for pieces published in (academic) journals. For an unpublished piece, use either the `@unpublished` or the `@misc` entry type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the references to get sorted alphabetically, i.e., if you want the references to appear in the order they are cited in the body of the document, do *not* use the `plainnat` bibliography style. Instead, use the `unsrtnat` bibliography style -- or some other bibliography style that doesn't perform alphabetical sorting.

[image]

Observe that the Gaillard entry now occurs *before* the Bell et al. entry in the bibliography, as the Gaillard piece is cited before the Bell et al. piece.

Do observe that you shouldn't use the `@article` entry type for the piece by Gaillard. Use the `@misc` entry type instead.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{sample.bib}
@article{bell_beyond_2009,
    title = {Beyond the Data Deluge},
    volume = {323},
    rights = {© 2009 American Association for the Advancement of Science},
    issn = {0036-8075, 1095-9203},
    url = {http://science.sciencemag.org/content/323/5919/1297},
    doi = {10.1126/science.1170411},
    abstract = {The demands of data-intensive science represent a challenge for diverse scientific communities.
    The demands of data-intensive science represent a challenge for diverse scientific communities.},
    pages = {1297--1298},
    number = {5919},
    journal = {Science},
    author = {Bell, Gordon and Hey, Tony and Szalay, Alex},
    year = {2009},
    langid = {english},
    pmid = {19265007}
}
@misc{noauthor_cern_nodate,
    title = {{CERN} Data Centre passes the 200-petabyte milestone~\textbar\ {CERN}},
    url = {https://home.cern/news/news/computing/cern-data-centre-passes-200-petabyte-milestone},
    year = {2018-12-11},
    author = {Mélissa Gaillard}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat} % not 'plainnat'
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces]{xurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\cite{noauthor_cern_nodate}, \cite{bell_beyond_2009}
\bibliography{sample}
\end{document}
```